# Почему не работает кнопка?

Tags: javascript

Укажите плиз на ошибку.

```
<form name="form">
<input type="button" value="
number" onClick="num";">&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="field" value="">
<script>
var a  =new Array ('1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','0');
var b =new Array ('D', 'X', 'H', 'S', 'V', 'P', 'U', 'A', 'N', 'T', 'R', 'M', 'Y', 'E', 'B', 'R', 'Z', 'K', 'W', 'F', 'G', 'C');

var wra = a[Math.round(Math.random()*(a.length-1))];
var wrb = b[Math.round(Math.random()*(b.length-1))];
   num = ( wra+wrb);
document.form.field.value = num ( wra+wrb);
</script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не улавливаю сути того, что Вы хотели сделать. num должна быть функцией или переменной? Если переменная, то какого эффекта Вы ждёте по клику по кнопке? В ином случае нужно писать onClick="num()" и тогда мне опять же не ясна вот эта строка "num = ( wra+wrb);".

Попробую предположить, чего Вы хотели добиться. Попробуйте вот так:

```
<form name="form">
<input type="button" value="number" onClick="num()" />&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="field" value="" />
</form>

<script>
var a  =new Array ('1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','0');
var b =new Array ('D', 'X', 'H', 'S', 'V', 'P', 'U', 'A', 'N', 'T', 'R', 'M', 'Y', 'E', 'B', 'R', 'Z', 'K', 'W', 'F', 'G', 'C');
function num(){
    var wra = a[Math.round(Math.random()*(a.length-1))];
    var wrb = b[Math.round(Math.random()*(b.length-1))];
    var result =  wra+wrb;
    document.form.field.value = result;
}
</script>
```

Comment: хочу чтобы номера чередовались а получается,что один номер в окошке и он не меняется.

Comment: @kot197676, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="form">
<input type="button" value="number" onclick="num()">&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="field" value="">
</form>

<script>
function num() {
    var a  =new Array ('1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','0');
    var b =new Array ('D', 'X', 'H', 'S', 'V', 'P', 'U', 'A', 'N', 'T', 'R', 'M', 'Y', 'E', 'B', 'R', 'Z', 'K', 'W', 'F', 'G', 'C');

    var wra = a[Math.round(Math.random()*(a.length-1))];
    var wrb = b[Math.round(Math.random()*(b.length-1))];
    var numb = wra+wrb;

    document.form.field.value = numb;
}

</script>
```

Comment: спасибо но чет цифры не меняются так же.

Comment: @kot197676, та не может быть =) http://jsfiddle.net/P799H/

Comment: Vladimir большое спасибо